# Cloud function some time throw me error Pubsub error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I used cloud function and some time cloud function throw me error look like :

```
https://guid-dot-uid-tp.appspot.com/_ah/push-handlers/pubsub/projects/name/topics/topic_name

User-Agent: CloudPubSub-google
```

Error 500 , Message :

> The request was aborted because there was no available instance. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability

Because i don't have any pubsub in project. I have only one trigger : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore.documentbuilder.html#onupdate

But i don't understand why some time it throw me error. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: After checking documentation I think this is firing on your document builder  `onUpdate` function but as a passing context in `EventContext` as type  `google.pubsub.topic.publish`  from your only event as mention on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions.eventcontext) So it might be an internal issue from using your `onUpdate`. Was this a one time issue?

Comment: @Betjens Thanks you for your answer. It some time throw error. Three time on one days or two time one days.

Comment: To complement, It might be due the load of your `onupdate` function being called reaching the limit acceptable. On [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability) , It states that there are limits for when this function can be called. Please check the [limits and quotas pages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#resource_limits) for firebase.

Comment: were you able to check the limit pages?